# How do I reschedule a failed Rufus every job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

I have a Rufus "every job" that runs periodically, but sometimes it may fail to perform it's task.

On failure, I would like to reschedule a retry soon rather than wait until the next cycle.

```rb
class PollProducts

  def initialize()
  end

  def call(job)
    puts "Updating products"

    begin
      # Do something that might fail
      raise if rand(3) == 1
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Request failed - recheduling: #{e}"
      # job.in("5s") <-- What can I do?
    end
  end
end

scheduler.every '6h', PollProducts.new, :first_in => '5s', :blocking => true
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this worked for me:

```
job.scheduler.in '5s', self
```